# Does Fu have a "super" transformation?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

The Dragon Ball Wikia doesnt list any transformation for Fu, but this more than a power-up looks like a transformation. The black aura alone could be a powerup, but his eyes turn red and his hair gets spiky similar to a super saiyan. Does any manga or videogame show Fu have a transformation or it's just a powerup? It's not only a semantic issue because a transformation allows the user to boost his power beyond the limits of his base form. I dont think there is anything official about this, but I think it's worth mentioning just in case, there are many fans already calling this "super Fu" or "super saiyan devil".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's the form called Super Mira as the name suggest it was first used by Mira by and since Fu is Mira's son i guess he can use it too.The form itself is just Super Saiyan but mutated by demon DNA.I'd link the wiki but i can't so try finding it as "Super Mira" there.